# Chrome extension popup with javascript

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've created a chrome extension.  When i click on the extension `popup.html` is displayed.  I want to execute this from my website.  So if i click from my website the chrome extension `popup.html` is displayed.  How do i implement this?

Here is my `manifest.json` but i don't know how to communicate between my website and the chrome extension.

```
{
"name":"My Website",
"version":"1.0",
"manifest_version":2,
"description":"My Website Chat Notification",
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.mywebsite.com/*"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
"browser_action": {

    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
}


}
```

Is this possible and how do i solve this? API?

Comment: I don't think you can open a Pop Up page pragmatically

Comment: i mean the extension is "activated".  Currently i click the extension and the action happens.  Can i call that action from my website?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the popup programmatically, you can't do this.

If you want to send message from web site to your extension, you can do it in this way:

## manifest.json

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["http//www.example.com/*"]
}
```

## extension.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
       // Your logic here
    });
```

## WebSite.js

```
var extensionId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var message = // Your content here
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(editorExtensionId, message,
  function(response) {
    // Your logic here
});
```

See more in https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external.

Comment: What would send a message do?  Could sending a message emulate clicking the extension?

Comment: No, you can't programmatically open the popup.